# Mylyn WikiText Extras won’t install in eclipse Oxygen, says Mylyn WikiText 3.0.6 is installed

Tags: java, eclipse

Vogella [suggests](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AsciiDoc/article.html#asciidocwrittertools) installing Mylyn WikiText Extras for editing asciidoc. But on my (just installed) Eclipse Oxygen Java EE, it refuses to install. According to [instructions](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/downloads/), I selected Mylyn WikiText Extras from the [Mylyn Docs](http://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/snapshots/nightly/docs/) Eclipse repository. Then Eclipse says:

```
 Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
 Software being installed: Mylyn WikiText Extras 3.0.14.201707112336 (org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.extras_feature.feature.group 3.0.14.201707112336)
  Software currently installed: Mylyn WikiText 3.0.6.201703111926 (org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext_feature.feature.group 3.0.6.201703111926)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Mylyn WikiText Tasks UI 3.0.6.201703111926 (org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.tasks.ui 3.0.6.201703111926)
    Mylyn WikiText Tasks UI 3.0.14.201707112336 (org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.tasks.ui 3.0.14.201707112336)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Mylyn WikiText Extras 3.0.14.201707112336 (org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.extras_feature.feature.group 3.0.14.201707112336)
    To: org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext_feature.feature.group [3.0.14.201707112336]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Mylyn WikiText 3.0.14.201707112336 (org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext_feature.feature.group 3.0.14.201707112336)
    To: org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.tasks.ui [3.0.14.201707112336]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Mylyn WikiText 3.0.6.201703111926 (org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext_feature.feature.group 3.0.6.201703111926)
    To: org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.tasks.ui [3.0.6.201703111926]
```

I tried to find [another](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Mylyn/Repositories) repository where Mylyn WikiText Extras 3.0.6 would be available, to no avail.

Eclipse also refuses to upgrade Mylyn. (Or I didn’t find how to.)

Same problem happens with the nightly snapshots [update site](http://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/snapshots/nightly/). And “Contact all update sites during install to find required software” is checked.

I suppose I could download another Eclipse release where Mylyn is not integrated, and then install Mylyn in there from scratch. But I’d prefer to stick to my Eclipse Java EE bundle, if possible.

Same problem when trying more recently with org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.tasks.ui [3.0.19.201709020037]

Answer (score 1):

**Add the update site http://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/snapshots/nightly/** and make sure *Contact all update sites during install to find required software* is checked.

Comment: I just edited the question to indicate that I had tried it already. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I suppose Eclipse error log would mark it? The error log (as per Error Log view) does not contain any error related to timeout, or any error related to installing components for that matter, apart from the one reporting the impossibility of installing, as indicated in the OP. Also, there does not appear to be any long delay where Eclipse would be timing out while trying to download something. Finally, the problem has happened systematically (at least five times) on two different computers of mine in two different places and networks on two different days.